# GitHub Actions install pdftk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-actions, pdftk

I'm trying to install **pdftk** for Github Actions Workflow. But it doesn't seem to be working. Any Idea, how to setup **PDFTK** for **Github Actions** ?

**Github Actions Workflow:**

```
on:
  push:
    branches: [setup_github]
  pull_request:
    branches: [setup_github]
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:10
        ports: ['5432:5432']
    steps:
    - name: Checkout
      uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up ruby
      uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version:  2.5.3
    - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.0.2
      with:
        cmd: install
    - name: Set up JDK
      uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: 1.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        sudo apt-get -yqq install libpq-dev
        sudo snap install pdftk
        sudo ln -fs /snap/pdftk/current/usr/bin/pdftk /usr/bin/pdftk
        wget -q -O /tmp/libpng12.deb http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libpng/libpng12-0_1.2.54-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I'm using following command in the code to check pdf files. tests are failing due to pdftk.

`cmd = "pdftk #{input_file_path} dump_data output 2>&1 >/dev/null"`

I'm using **Ruby on Rails (2.5.3)**, **Rspecs**

Comment: what is the exact result  of the command or error, when you run the actions?

Comment: Same issue here. Error message "Package 'pdftk' has no installation candidate"